# How could the Count of Monte Cristo disappear when other people weren't looking?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Season 6, Episode 2, *A Bitter Draught*, we are introduced to the Count of Monte Cristo, Edmond Dantès. In his first appearance, he talks with Henry at Granny's. Henry looks at the story book for a second or two, then turns back to find that Edmond has completely vanished. We don't see him in the diner, and there was no sound that the door opened.

Later in the episode, we see this happen again. When Regina meets with him, he throws a sword at her and she stops it with magic. When she looks up from the sword a second later, he's disappeared.

How could Edmond do this? He's never shown to have learned magic as a result of trying to get his revenge, and there is no purple smoke that would surely appear if the Evil Queen tried to teleport him. So how did he vanish without a trace?

Comment: Maybe they decided to combine him with [Gully Foyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination) and he can jaunte.

Comment: *shrug* Same way Batman does. Apparently it's a power gained through brooding.

Comment: It certainly sounds easier than disappearing when people *are* looking!